# Adding nvd to map in systemjs

Tags: d3.js, angular, nvd3.js, systemjs, ng2-nvd3

I have an angular2 application where i wish to use rickshaw. 
This requires the following: 
d3, nvd3 and ng2-nvd3.
I have these in my lib folder:

[image]

And my systemjs.config.js map looks as follows:

[image]

However, when run this i get an error: 
[image]

telling me it has not been implemented.
Can someone please tell me what i´m missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What build/bundling tool are you using?  Are you sure those files are getting bundled up in your application?  Take a look at the network section, is there an attempt to load the nv.d3.js file that fails or is there no attempt to load the file at all?

Comment: Hello. there are no attempt to load said file.
Where am i to include this?

Comment: If there is no attempt at all do you have any import statement for nvd3?

Comment: Yes. ng2-nvd3 has been imported. 
I have followed this https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3

Comment: Ok, well the line `import {nvD3} from 'ng2-nvd3'` should trigger a lookup of some kind of file.  Can you debug at that line and look at the network tab's list of files both before and after that line to see what gets fetched as a result of that call?

Comment: hi. thanks for all your help. I the erorr was my understanding of systemjs.
I have included 

     <script src="lib/ng2-nvd3/node_modules/d3/d3.js"></script>
     <script src="lib/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
to my index.html, though i´m not sure this is the right way...

Comment: It isn't really the right way.  You shouldn't have to use script elements.  The `import` call should trigger a fetch of those `.js` files for you.  Some frameworks may break at production if they do something like bundle all of your vendor `.js` files into a single file.

Comment: Specifically, `import {nvD3} from 'ng2-nvd3'` should compile down to something like `var nvd3_1 = require('ng2-nvd3');`  The require statement should then trigger a lookup through SystemJS to fetch the appropriate files.  However, I have noticed that your script tag is referencing `lib/ng2-nvd3/build/nv.d3.js` while your `system-config.ts` appears to be setup to look for `lib/ng2-nvd3` and is missing the `build` part of the path.  Although I have no idea if you have some `packages` configuration later in your `system-config.ts` that addresses this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding

```
lib/ng2-nvd3/node_modules/d3/d3.js
lib/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js
```

to the index.html solved my problem. 
I´m however not sure this is the right way to do this.